# how to solve aptana CRC porblem and invalid command line

Tags: php

when I would like to install aptana3.6.1, it showed the error:

> (nodejs CRC error.)

I have tried the following: `cmd>aptana.exe/passive/norestart`.

Unfortunately, it showed invalid command line. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: just download [node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: it is no use. I  tried